# How to display a Jupyter notebook as dashboard?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, dashboard

I'd like to display an Jupyter (IPython) notebook as a (non-interactive) dashboard.

Coming from a regular notebook, the changes are:

- displaying the notebook so it is not editable (like nbviewer.jupyter.org)
- rerunning the notebook on a regular timer (like Kernel > Restart & Run All)
- hiding the code (like jupyter_contrib_nbextensions "Hide input all", or something similar, but should be enabled by default when notebook loads)
- (optional but nice) having multiple tabs or sections that the notebook can cycle through

What is the best way to do that?  Is it better to do in a notebook, or convert the notebook to something that just generates a static html website?  If notebook, how to set it up so it is not editable and so it gets rerun regularly?

Comment: Is a Jupyter notebook the only sensible way to present what you want to be presenting? Given that the whole thing is strongly focused on interactivity, you'll probably end up fighting it pretty hard to turn it into something that it's not.

Comment: @pvg You're right, that is a concern.  On the plus side, this would be developed as a notebook for the forseeable future, it is nice to be able to just present the same notebook to a dashboard, rather than always figuring out how to create a dashboard from each updated version of the notebook.

Comment: Doesn't nbviewer get you there? It gives no access to the notebook itself, just a rendered view and appears to be configurable to periodically pull and re-render the notebook. And it's open source.

Comment: @pvg As I'm digging into it, nbviewer is a bit of a different use case (eg my notebook is not entirely trivial to run inside docker), but `jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute test.ipynb` gets most of the way there.  Main thing that's left is hiding the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate HTML to embed into your dashboard. By using

> --no-input
>
> Exclude input cells and output prompts from converted document.
>
> This mode is ideal for generating code-free reports.

Just run

```
jupyter nbconvert \
  --no-input \
  --to html
  --execute test.ipynb
```

You can even generate a default config file with

```
jupyter nbconvert --generate-config
```

then set

```
## This allows you to exclude code cell inputs from all templates if set to True.
c.TemplateExporter.exclude_input = True
```

together with

```
## This allows you to exclude output prompts from all templates if set to True.
c.TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt = True
```

You can use a custom config by

```
--config=<Full path of a config file>
```